# JSF inputText reads value only with required="true"

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can anyone explain why `h:inputText` must have `required="true"` when setting the property in controller and updating with ajax(See example below)?

Does not work:

```
<h:inputText id="textFieldId" value="#{model.itemValue}">
```

Works:

```
<h:inputText id="textFieldId" value="#{model.itemValue}" required="true">
```

Action:

```
<p:commandLink value="edit">
   <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{controller.edit(item)}" process="@this" update="@form"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Idea behind is that I want to press button for item and be able to edit so I need to propagate this item to inputText.

I dont see any reason for having required set to true.

Thanks

Comment: `p:commandLink` is already ajax enabled... No need for the `p:ajax` tag inside it!!! And using `process="this"` prevents the input to be 'ignored', so please create a [mcve] to show the real intention

Comment: Actually your proposal solved the problem. Removed ajax and added to command link as action. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrimeFaces [`p:commandLink`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandLink.xhtml) is by default already ajax enabled, so there is no need to nest a `p:ajax` tag inside it.

```
<p:commandLink value="edit" actionListener="#{controller.edit(item)}"
     process="@this" update="@form"/>
```

But keep in mind that if you add a `process="@this"`, the input is not processed on the server, just the commandLink. If the 'item' field is passed correctly in this case is unclear to me.